# How do I use the current system interpreter in PyCharm?

Tags: python, configuration, pycharm

PyCharm provides a way to specify interpreters (as a default for new projects, individually for projects, and for individual run scripts and their templates). But if I specify the system's default interpreter — e.g. in `/usr/bin/python` or, for a Homebrew system, in `/usr/local/bin/python`  — the "interpreter paths" that PyCharm lists (in *Preferences > Project Interpreter*) [are wrong](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-16382): they include not only the paths for the selected interpreter, but also those for earlier versions.

For example after an upgrade from version OLD to NEW of Homebrew's interpreter, there is not only a complete set of `/usr/local/Cellar/python/NEW/...` paths, as expected, but also a full set of `/usr/local/Cellar/python/OLD/...` paths listed. The only way I've found to fix this is to delete the offending interpreter from PyCharm's preferences entirely — everywhere it is used — and add it back.

Is there a less error-prone way of telling PyCharm to simply use the system's current Python interpreter: the one that will run at the command line with `python` and is reported by `which python`?

Comment: Maybe this site helps? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add-existing-interpreter

Answer (score 1):

It takes few steps to achieve what you are looking for.

#### Go to interpreter settings

[image]

Click on "Show All".

#### Select your python system interpreter

[image]

If you do not have your python system interpreter listed, you may have to add it.

##### Extra steps (if not listed)

[image]

Click the plus icon

[image]

Select "Existing environment" and click the three little dots.
From now set the path of your python interpreter and validate.

#### UPDATE

Actually you will a great answer from the comment under your question.